# Recommended development platform for an accessible mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, text-to-speech, midi

I'm preparing to create a open source mobile app for learning to type in Braille. The app will need to:

- Access up to 6 simultaneous touch points
- Generate text-to-speech audio on the fly
- Play MIDI sounds with 6 simultaneous channels, generated on the fly
- Connect with a BlueTooth device

Ideally, I would like to create the app once in one development environment, and then deploy it to Android, iOS and other devices.

- PhoneGap
- Titanium
- LiveCode

However, as far as I can tell from my research, none of these gives me access to all the native features that my project will need.

I would be interested to hear from developers who are working in these and similar development environments on how easy it is to handle the four requirements I have listed above.

Answer (score 1):

With all those requirements i'd go for [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?_bt=44014802708&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=Cj0KEQjw8aeiBRCknPXk-u_V_4gBEiQAD2-mgQfDqfK9jJ-Lfg9rxJrRAyCJlMHDvlEokCKCClZ-tloaAnHs8P8HAQ), i know it can deal with text-tp-speech, bluetooth and multiple touch inputs but you have to check whether it supports your MIDI requirement.
And of course you can port to all platforms.

- [Bluetooth Chat Sample Application](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/android/Bluetooth/)
- [TextToSpeech class](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech)